# Manipulating textarea when using ajax to get data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi all I'm using the following code to add data to my text area-

```
$('a#mod_description_onclick').click(function(){ 
    $('#MOD-DESCRIPTION').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'}); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "tab.description.php",
        success: function(response){
            $('#MOD-DESCRIPTION .modal-body').html(response);
        }
    }); 
})
```

and the following code to count the characters when typing-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var left = 2000
    var txtrest = '<?php echo lang("SYSTEM_CHARECTERS_LEFT");?>';
    $('#text_counter').text(txtrest + ' ' + left);

        $('#field-ta').keyup(function () {

        left = 2000 - $(this).val().length;

        if(left < 0){
            $('#text_counter').addClass("overlimit");
             $('#submit_description').attr("disabled", true);
        }
        if(left > 1950){
            $('#text_counter').addClass("overlimit");
             $('#submit_description').attr("disabled", true);
        }
        else{
            $('#text_counter').removeClass("overlimit");
            $('#submit_description').attr("disabled", false);
        }

        $('#text_counter').text(txtrest + ' ' + left);
    });
});
```

To help here is the contents of my **tab.description.php** file that is called by the ajax to get data from my mysql and refresh the contents of the `textarea`.

```
<textarea  rows="5" maxlength="2000" class="form-control " id="field-ta" name="field-ta" >
   <?php echo get_profile_value('5001') ?>
</textarea>
```

So my problem is the following if I hard-code the textarea instead of using the ajax method  my character counter works. or in other words updating my modal form with ajax stops my character counter from working .

Where could the problem be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that using AJAX triggers keyup events - only actually typing into the text field will trigger that. I'm not sure what the best solution is, though this should work:

```
function countChars = function () {
    left = 2000 - $(this).val().length;

    if(left < 0){
        $('#text_counter').addClass("overlimit");
        $('#submit_description').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    if(left > 1950){
        $('#text_counter').addClass("overlimit");
        $('#submit_description').attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else{
        $('#text_counter').removeClass("overlimit");
        $('#submit_description').attr("disabled", false);
    }

    $('#text_counter').text(txtrest + ' ' + left);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var left = 2000
    var txtrest = '<?php echo lang("SYSTEM_CHARECTERS_LEFT");?>';
    $('#text_counter').text(txtrest + ' ' + left);

        $('#field-ta').keyup(countChars);
});
```

Note that I have extracted the keyup event to another function, so that it can be called by the AJAX fucntion, below:

```
$('a#mod_description_onclick').click(function(){ 
    $('#MOD-DESCRIPTION').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'}); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "tab.description.php",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#MOD-DESCRIPTION .modal-body').html(response);
            countChars();
        }
    }); 
})
```

Alternatively, you can trigger a manual keyup event, like so:

```
$('a#mod_description_onclick').click(function(){ 
    $('#MOD-DESCRIPTION').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'}); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "tab.description.php",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#MOD-DESCRIPTION .modal-body').html(response);
            $('#MOD-DESCRIPTION .modal-body').trigger('keyup');
        }
    }); 
})
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the character counter is triggered by keyup event, but using ajax doesn't emit the keyup event